# >= GETDATE() not returning rows with today's date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, getdate

```
---------------------
| ID  |     date    |
|-----+-------------|
|  1  |  2013-12-30 |
|  2  |  2014-01-03 |
|  3  |  2014-02-02 |
---------------------
```

column `ID` is `int` type

column `date` is `Date` type

When i use `SELECT CAST (getdate() as date) currentDay, ID FROM table WHERE date >= GETDATE()`, it only returns:

```
--------------------------------------
|  currentDay   |  ID  |     date    |
|---------------+------+-------------|
| 2013-12-30    |   2  |  2014-01-03 |
| 2013-12-30    |   3  |  2014-02-02 |
--------------------------------------
```

it does not return the row with `ID=1`.

In other words, `>=GETDATE()` does not return rows with today's date.

What did I do wrongly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't return any rows with today's date because `GETDATE()` gives date **and time**. So, in your example, converting `2013-12-30` to a `DATETIME` gives you `2013-12-30 00:00:00`, which isn't equal or greater than `2013-12-30 12:09:35` (the result of `GETDATE()` for me in this moment). You need to use:

`WHERE date >= CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())`

Answer (score 1):

The GETDATE() function returns the current date and time (i.e. including the time part).
So it is normal that today's date (without the time part) is smaller than GETDATE() ( unless you run your query at midnight precisely ). This is why you don't get the expected result.